PySpark issue with user defined function
Why does my pyspark application fail with user defined function?
    multiplier = udf(lambda x: float(x) * 100.0, FloatType())
    df = df.select(multiplier(df['value']).alias('value_percent'))

The error thrown is

Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) (127.0.0.1 executor driver):
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly
....
java.io.EOFException

But even stranger is that the same code (with same UDF function and same dataset) actually works on a jupyter note.

spark version: 3.5.3
python version: 3.11.9
os: Windows.

Turns out it is required to set environment variables SPARK_HOME and PYTHONPATH as mentioned here https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/how-to-import-pyspark-in-python-script/
It is strange that the application only failed when using UDF functions. Also, there were no error messages regarding missing SPARK_HOME environment variable. Hope future releases of spark detects and reports this during application start time.
BTW, it's much easier to just install the findspark package and initialize it in your code before you try setting the environment variables by hand.  I had actually used findspark in my Jupyter note which is why that was working but not the actual application.
